# Speed up NDSolve for a changing equation?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning

For physics research, there is a differential equation that I simulate again and again. It would be wonderful to speed it up. Each time I run it, part of the input function $I(t)$ changes. It takes a few minutes each time, and after running a few hundred iterations per day, it is eating up a bunch of time. Each time I run it, the input function $I(t)$ only changes a little bit, and the output $\textbf{m(t)}$ also only changes a little bit.

The equation is the [Landau -Lifshitz-Gilbert-Slonczewski Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation#Landau.E2.80.93Lifshitz.E2.80.93Gilbert.E2.80.93Slonczewski_equation) (LLGS) :

$$
\frac{d\textbf{m}}{dt}=-|\gamma|\textbf{m} \times \textbf{B}_\textrm{eff}-|\gamma|\alpha_\textrm{g}\textbf{m}\times[\textbf{m}\times\textbf{B}_\textrm{eff}]+|\gamma|\alpha_\textrm{j}~I(t)~\textbf{m}\times[\textbf{m}\times\textbf{p}]
$$

In this equation, I am solving for $\bf{m}=\bf{m}(t)$, which is magnetization (a 3-D vector). $I(t)$ is current, an input parameter that is a function of time, which changes each time the LLGS is solved. $t$ for time, $\gamma$, $\alpha_\textrm{g}$, $\alpha_\textrm{j}$ are scalar constants, and $\textbf{B}_\textrm{eff}$ and $\textbf{p}$ are constant vectors.

Here is my code for solving this equation:

```
gamma = 176;
alphag = 0.01;
alphajConstant = 0.00603;
p = {Cos[Pi/6], 0, Sin[Pi/6]};
current[t_] := Piecewise[{{3, t <= 50}, {(5-3)/(150-50) (t - 50) + 3, 50 < t < 150}, {5, t >= 150}}] + .01*Sin[2*Pi*30*t];
Beff[t_] := {0, 0, 1.5 - 0.8*(m[t].{0, 0, 1})};
cons[t_] := -gamma*Cross[m[t], Beff[t]];
tGilbdamp[t_] := alphag*Cross[m[t], cons[t]];
tSlondamp[t_] := current[t]*alphajConstant*gamma*Cross[m[t], Cross[m[t], p]];
LLGS = {m'[t] == cons[t] + tGilbdamp[t] + tSlondamp[t], m[0] == {0, 0, 1}};
sol1 = NDSolve[LLGS, {m}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]; 
mm[t_] = m[t] /. sol1[[1]] ;
```

To reiterate, this equation is solving for $\textbf{m(t)}$=`m[t]` with a chaging input parameter $I(t)$=`current[t]`  .  What might change? Perhaps a second current & simulation would look like this:

```
current[t_] := Piecewise[{{3.1, t <= 60}, {(5.1-3.1)/(200-60) (t - 60) + 3.1, 60< t < 200}, {5.1, t >= 200}}] + .05*Sin[2*Pi*31*t];
LLGS = {m'[t] == cons[t] + tGilbdamp[t] + tSlondamp[t], m[0] == {0, 0, 1}};
sol1 = NDSolve[LLGS, {m}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
```

---

What I am considering:

One thought is to use  [the functionality for NDSolve Reinitialize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) . Will this require me to change how my `LLGS` equation is formatted? I assume that to use this I will need to change how `current[t]` appears in my equation, and have it instead be a set of initial conditions. Is this the best option to speed things up?

Perhaps I should define a method? Perhaps there a way to use previous solutions as a starting point?

Is there a better way to make this go faster? Both individually, and in repetition?

Comment: Please show us a minimal working example, currently there're several parameters missing in your code.

Comment: @xzczd I have added working code.

Comment: I do not think equation processing is a significant issue here. Your system is highly oscillatory and simply requires a huge number of increments.  I don't see anything you can do but to brute force crunch out each solution.

Comment: ``NDSolve`Reinitialize[]`` will save significant time only if the time for ``NDSolve`ProcessEquations[]`` is significantly long. I suspect that the time taken for ``NDSolve`Iterate[]`` will be at least a few orders of magnitude greater. In other words, I don't expect reinitialization to save much time.

Comment: Just noticed you've removed the introduction for LLGS from your question, may I ask why?

Comment: I was worried it didn't add anything to the question.

Comment: The background information definitely makes the question more useful. For example, with the words "LLGS" "Landau -Lifshitz-Gilbert-Slonczewski" etc. it's much easier for someone who reads this post once to find out this post later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can speed up the evaluation a good bit by breaking the solution domain so you get rid of the `Piecewise`:

```
gamma = 176;
alphag = 0.01;
alphajConstant = 0.00603;
p = {Cos[Pi/6], 0, Sin[Pi/6]};
current[t_] := 3 + .01*Sin[2*Pi*30*t];
Beff[t_] := {0, 0, 1.5 - 0.8*(m[t].{0, 0, 1})};
cons[t_] := -gamma*Cross[m[t], Beff[t]];
tGilbdamp[t_] := alphag*Cross[m[t], cons[t]];
tSlondamp[t_] := 
  current[t]*alphajConstant*gamma*Cross[m[t], Cross[m[t], p]];
LLGS = {m'[t] == cons[t] + tGilbdamp[t] + tSlondamp[t], 
   m[0] == {0, 0, 1}};
sol1 = NDSolve[LLGS, {m}, {t, 0, 50}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
current[t_] := (5 - 3)/(150 - 50) (t - 50) + 3 + .01*Sin[2*Pi*30*t];
m50 = (m /. First@sol1)[50];
LLGS = {m'[t] == cons[t] + tGilbdamp[t] + tSlondamp[t], m[50] == m50};
sol2 = NDSolve[LLGS, {m}, {t, 50, 150}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
current[t_] := 5 + .01*Sin[2*Pi*30*t];
m150 = (m /. First@sol2)[150];
LLGS = {m'[t] == cons[t] + tGilbdamp[t] + tSlondamp[t], 
   m[150] == m150};
sol3 = NDSolve[LLGS, {m}, {t, 150, 200}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
```

This runs in about 3-4 seconds..

plot the third component using `ListPlot` to plot the actual solution points.

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[
   Transpose[{Flatten@(m /. sol1[[1]])["Grid"], (m /. sol1[[1]])[
       "ValuesOnGrid"][[All, 3]]}]],
  ListPlot[
   Transpose[{Flatten@(m /. sol2[[1]])["Grid"], (m /. sol2[[1]])[
       "ValuesOnGrid"][[All, 3]]}]],
  ListPlot[
   Transpose[{Flatten@(m /. sol3[[1]])["Grid"], (m /. sol3[[1]])[
       "ValuesOnGrid"][[All, 3]]}]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

components 1 and 2..

[image]

Comment: This solution works well, and is how I implemented it.

Answer (score 13):

You can also convert the `Piecewise[]` into terms of `UnitStep[]`, using `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``, and get a significant speed-up:

```
current[t_] := 
  Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    Piecewise[{
      {3, t <= 50},
      {.02 (t - 50) + 3, 50 < t < 150},
      {5, t >= 150}}] + .01*Sin[2*Pi*30*t];
LLGS = {m'[t] == cons[t] + tGilbdamp[t] + tSlondamp[t],  m[0] == {0, 0, 1}};

sol1 = NDSolve[LLGS, {m}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> ∞]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {2.24653, Null}  *)
```

Comment: This solution works well.